# eclipse doesn't show an active device in the Run Configurations window

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt

I want to download an application to an active device from eclipse SDK.
The device communicates with eclipse. I can see it in the DDMS window, but the device doesn't appear in the Run Configurations window.
When I click  Reset adb in the DDMS window I receive the following error message:

```
[2014-02-18 08:50:58 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2014-02-18 08:50:58 - DeviceMonitor] Sending Tracking request failed!
[2014-02-18 08:50:58 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2014-02-18 08:51:00 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
```

I also tried to reset the server from the command line with the adb kill-server and adb start-server without success.

I changed the USB port and tried with an additional active device receiving the same error message.

Android Developer Tools
Build: v22.3.0-887826

Eclipse Platform
Version: 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7
Build id: M20130204-1200

Comment: Have you turned on USB debugging and selected the 'Unknown Sources' checkbox in the device settings?

Comment: yes yes USB debugging is on in Developper options and Unknown sources is checked on  under Security  settings.

Comment: Hi, the problem was "android:minSdkVersion". I tried to install the app directly from the console and receive a message error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
Means that you're trying to install an app that has a higher minSdkVersion specified in its manifest than the device's API level. Change that number to 8 and it should work.

Comment: I changed the minSdkVersion and the active device appears and I was able to load the application.

Answer (score 0):

**This happens because the ADB Driver on your Computer is not installed. If you're on Windows then follow the steps below.**

If you're using any other OS or Windows Version then refer this link http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

1. Open Device Manager and check that your device has installed drivers or not.
2. If Drivers are not installed then right click on device and select **Update Driver Software**.  This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
3. Select **Browse my computer for driver software** and click **Next**.
   Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in *(your_sdk_location)\extras\google\usb_driver.*)
4. Click **Next** to install the driver.